# Elasticsearch multiple index request on same document id in bulk api

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using elastic search 6.0 and using bulk indexing to index many documents in a single request using “index” action. In a single request we can have a scenario where there are multiple “index” requests on same document. Will ES fail the bulk request in such case OR it will process all of them in order?

Edit1: I use a script for indexing in bulk request where we are handling out of order updates. So as long as all “index” requests are getting processed, we don’t have any issue.

Comment: process all of them in order

Comment: So you mean ES will process them in order as specified in request? Or in order processing is only limited to dispatching request to other nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES will not fail, but it is not necessarily clear which indexing operation will "win". It might be the last one but since all operations in the bulk batch might be spread over several ingest nodes, and not all of those nodes process the indexing operations at the same rate, it might not be clear which operation will be processed first and which will be processed last.

The only guarantee that you have is that in the response, you'll get the state of each operation **in the same order as specified in the request batch**.

If your index has only one primary shard, then the order in which you submit the operations will be the same order as the one those operations are processed, hence the last one wins, but if you have more than one primary shard on more than one node, then you can't really know.

A better question would be why do you submit several indexing operations per document knowing in advance that only one will win?

Comment: This is an existing setup which has been there for quite sometime and we have not seen any issues as such. I was trying to reason about the current logic and seeing if this could be an issue. Also what is the logic to assign requests to ingest node? Since documents with same id would go to same primary shard, doesn’t that ensure ordering as such ?

Comment: Updated my question based on your answer

Comment: Why not simply keep the last indexing operation instead of sending all of them knowing that the last one will override all previous ones anyway and thus will make the segments grow faster because of all the intermediary versions that are marked as deleted and will need to be purged during merge operations?

Comment: I understand what would be the solution but just wanted to know would it not work with current setup given that we already handle out of order processing

Comment: "Since documents with same id would go to same primary shard, doesn’t that ensure ordering as such" -- @Val this one is a good question.. Can you please answer this one as well. Thanks!

Comment: Then, it will sure work, and never complain about multiple indexing operations for the same document.

Comment: "Since documents with same id would go to same primary shard, doesn’t that ensure ordering as such" That's true as well. But still, it's a waste of bandwidth, CPU, memory, thread pools to send several indexing operations for the same document in the same batch since we know in advance that only one will win. It would be very different for partial updates though